# How to cancel executing Hangfire batch child jobs?

Tags: c#, hangfire

## Problem

Simply put, `BatchJob.Cancel` doesn't cancel already-running child jobs, and they instead run to completion, but cancelling the child job by id (when it's running) using `BackgroundJob.Delete` results in the child job being cancelled. Injecting either `JobCancellationToken` or `CancellationToken` into the method yields the same problem.

## Minimal Example

```cs
public class BatchTest
{
    public async Task Method1(CancellationToken ct)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Started 1");
        try
        {
            // meaningless work to simulate some long-running task
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30), ct);
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Cancelled 1");
            return;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Completed 1");
    }
}
```

Client code:

```cs
string? childId = null;
var batchJobId = BatchJob.StartNew(act =>
{
    childId = act.Enqueue<BatchTest>(t => t.Method1(default));
});

Console.WriteLine("Scheduled");

// Uncomment to immediately cancel (batch children will correctly never start)
// BatchJob.Cancel(batchJobId);

// For the sake of this example, we'll use this code to
// detect when the child job actually starts. In the real
// code, I don't do/need to do this, but I do need the batch
// to be cancellable.
while (true)
{
    var details = JobStorage.Current.GetMonitoringApi().JobDetails(childId);
    if (details.History.Any(h => h.StateName == ProcessingState.StateName))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Started");
        break;
    }
}

// Allow some time for the job to do some "work" and then cancel it
await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
BatchJob.Cancel(batchJobId);
//BackgroundJob.Delete(childId!);
Console.WriteLine("Cancelled batch");
```

If I cancel the batch job as above, `Method1` will first output `"Started 1"` and after 30s will output `"Completed 1"`. It doesn't register that the cancellation has even occurred.

However, if I comment out `BatchJob.Cancel(batchJobId);` and uncomment `BackgroundJob.Delete(childId!);`, the method correctly prints `"Started 1"` followed by `"Cancelled 1"`.

And, of course, if I cancel the batch before it gets picked up for execution, it simply never runs. That part works correctly, at least.

## Question

From D.A. I feel that I might be misunderstanding what batch cancellation is for, though D.A. even suggests that it sets the batch to deleted, so surely that should also handle the child jobs?

I can't find any way of getting the child job IDs by batch ID, so it's not like I have a means to manually cancel them all without first saving them all in my database.

How can I make batch cancellation work as I expected it to? I'm open to creating an extension method on `IBackgroundJob` if it allows me to cancel all of the child jobs.

Comment: If I remember correctly Hangfire has its own cancellation token: `JobCancellationToken`. It contains an actual `CancellationToken`. If you want your jobs to be cancellable you need to use it as an argument and forward the `ShutdownToken` property (the actual cancellation token) to the methods you want to cancel.

Comment: This should work for jobs that already started, the ones that not yet started are handled by their states.

Comment: @eldar I've tried both and neither work if I cancel the batch.

Comment: You may be right, that memory belongs to `BackgroundJobs` not the batches, I remember now I never used Batch jobs.

Comment: Which version of Hangfire ? Is it Hangfire Pro ?

Comment: @ChinmayT yes, the latest release versions of Hangfire and Hangfire.Pro.

Answer (score 0):

The Hangfire Server uses multiple threads to perform background jobs. Meaning it can process a background job per thread within the Hangfire server. This allows you to execute background jobs concurrently. By default, the number of threads it uses is 5 per Processor Count. For the **BatchJob** it uses thread pool. In a thread pool you can't cancel a worker thread. Once put in there you will have to wait until its completion or implement a custom **CancellationToken** mechanism to stop them. The **BatchJob.Cancel(batchId)** just set the *Deleted* state to prevent the other scheduled working threads to start.

Comment: _"In a thread pool you can't cancel a worker thread."_ - That doesn't entirely make sense, since I can cancel the individual child job in the batch by calling `BackgroundJob.Delete(childId!);`. If what you were saying is true, I shouldn't be able to cancel it at all, right?

Comment: And does `BackgroundJob.Delete(childId!);` do something different to _"just set the Deleted state"_?

Comment: BackgroundJob.Delete(childId!) set the Detele state only for that one. Check (https://api.hangfire.io/html/M_Hangfire_BackgroundJob_Delete.htm)

Comment: Yes, I understand that. But you're saying that jobs run this way can't be cancelled, even though I've demonstrated in my question that they can be. If `BatchJob.Cancel`sets all the child jobs to a deleted state, and `BackgroundJob.Delete` can be used to set an individual job to a deleted state, why is it that the latter works with the cancellation token passed to the method, but the former does not?

Comment: I don't know exactly what is happening in  your example, i've answered you the 2 questions you ask... ("How to cancel executing Hangfire batch child jobs" and "Am I misunderstanding what batch cancellation is for?"

Comment: You haven't really answered how I should do that, to be honest. I don't think your answer is even correct regarding the behaviour of batch cancellation, based on my observations.

Comment: I did. Read the documentation (https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-methods/using-batches.html#cancellation-of-a-batch). U will have to build your own cancel mechanism...

Comment: So, armed with only the batch id, how do I cancel the child jobs? The documentation doesn't mention that.

Comment: I don't suppose you have an actual solution for me, do you? I do have this 300 rep bounty that expires at 10:37 UTC and nobody seems to want to provide an answer.

Comment: There is no out of the box solution, that is why you have no answers. The hangfire uses the .Net infrastructure and there is no way to cancel a thread in the threadpool except to build your own one. Also Microsoft doc is telling u this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/cancellation-in-managed-threads#code-example

Comment: What does this have to do with the threadpool? Hangfire supports `CancellationToken`, and has its own `JobCancellationToken`. Clearly the running jobs can be cancelled because, when I have the cihld job id, I can cancel it (even though it's running on a different machine!). That Microsoft documentation is about threading, not Hangfire.

Comment: Simply put: if I run Hangfire as a server on machine A, and launch a "client" application on machine B (it does not process jobs, only adds them to the same Hangfire queue), then I can cancel an individual job via `BackgroundJob.Delete(childId!);` and that will result in the `CancellationToken` to be cancelled on machine A. I have tested this, and can confirm that this works like this. The code in the question comes from a project architected like this. My entire question is, and always has been, how to get that to work for cancelling via the batch the child job belongs to.

Comment: U don't get it .... BackgroundJob is on dedicated threads see doc (https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/#server) is also telling u there "not thread pool’s". An Batch is done on  thread pool (https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-processing/configuring-degree-of-parallelism.html). And in the thread pool u can't cancel.

Comment: I'm so tired of _you_ not getting it. Look at the code in my question, and answer this question: why does `BackgroundJob.Delete(childId!);` work when the job that `childId` represents is being run in a batch? According to you, cancelling such a job isn't possible just using Hangfire, and yet somehow it gets cancelled because it hits the `Console.WriteLine("Cancelled 1");` line, but never hits that line if I don't call `BackgroundJob.Delete(childId!);`.

Comment: Your example is wrong... u miss expect the results. Read also "BackgroundJob.Enqueue" (https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-methods/calling-methods-in-background.html) - "Enqueued jobs are handled by a dedicated pool of worker threads ... So, the job is removed only after processing succeeds. Even if a process was terminated during the performance, Hangfire will perform compensation logic to guarantee the processing of each job."

Comment: What do you mean by _"u miss expect the results"_?

Comment: I direct your attention to [Using Cancellation Tokens](https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-methods/using-cancellation-tokens.html) anyway.